# Excluding new items from a discount in Catalog Price Rules

Tags: price, catalog, rules

I work in a boutique and am adding new season merchandise to the site.

We have a sale running for all previous season items. When I am adding a new item [say a handbag], there is a Catalog Price Rule for 10% off handbags.

I want to exclude this new merchandise from the sale, but can't figure out how. I've tried a few different things, and nothing has worked. By category, some handbags need to be on sale but not all. Tried restricting by item number, no luck.

When managing the new product, I see on the tab settings there is a box for "Do not discount." That reads 0 by default. I've tried changing that too, but no luck.

Anyone have any advice out there?

Thanks-

rachel

Answer (score 1):

You need something you can distinguish the items.

I recommend to just put all the old stuff into a hidden category and just discount this category.

The alternative is to set the new articles to new from to and exclude them. Or you have a new attribute which does this and is added to the salesrule.

But as I said, I would stay with the first idea.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would normally approach this it sounds like you have already setup part of the rule. Although perhaps not completely configured it.

**The Attribute**

The Do Not Discount attribute on the product should be an attribute setup in the Catalog -> Attributes.

The value of "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" needs to be configured to Yes.

Then ensure the product you wish to prevent the discount applying to is set to not receive the discount (Do Not Discount = Yes)

**Modify your catalog rule**
Configure your discount rule and in the Conditions section add a new condition. You should see under the conditions to add there will be your "Do not Discount" Select it, and you will have some additional options to configure based on this.

When you add this, it will default to "is" it could be is not you use instead for rules but in this case ensure it is set to is, and the value is then set to match the value of the Do not discount - Yes.

When you apply the rules any product which has this value set up will be excluded from the rule and get its normal price.